# onListItemClick method not called when I use Checkox in list

Tags: android, android-widget, listactivity, listadapter

Hi guys I am new to android...I want to display a dynamic list of CheckBox and on Clicking multiple of those CheckBoxes i want their data in a single string...But my problem is that i am unable to call onListItemClick method if I use checkBox in my List...

It is my understanding and experience however that putting a focusable view in the list item prevents the firing of onListItemClick() in the ListActivity when the list item is clicked.
But can anyone Plz give me  solution...

I have referred links like

[How to fire onListItemClick in Listactivity with buttons in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821871/android-how-to-fire-onlistitemclick-in-listactivity-with-buttons-in-list)

[Android ListActivity onListItemClick calls adapter getView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023074/android-listactivity-onlistitemclick-calls-adapter-getview)

but unable to find a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it working you can set Checkboxes and other fields in the ListItem unclickable and unfocusable, by properties:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: But i have a small question...what if i store the clicks on Checkboxes and store it in List and then convert the list into single String..???

Comment: you can have a boolean array equal to the size of listitems, and can toggle each item on item click method callback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the checkbox as not focusable in the adapter class,  like this:

```
        yourCheckbox.setFocusable(false);
```

And in the xml file as well:

```
        android:focusable="false"
```